# Is the Hinduism we follow today baseless from a Vedic Perspective?

Tags: vedas, puranas, shiva-purana, vedic-gods, vishnu-purana

The *Vedic* (*Rgvedic primarily*) texts are quite different from the *Puranic* stories we know (and love) today. Does this mean the *Puranic* deities* we worship and stories we read are false from a *Vedic* perspective?

**brahmA, sarasvatI, mahAviSNu, lakSmI, shiva, pArvatI, etc.* described and decorated in Puranas such as viSNupurANa, shivapurANa, etc.

EDIT: I posted [this Question on Quora](https://www.quora.com/The-Vedic-texts-are-quite-different-from-the-Puranic-stories-we-know-and-love-today-Does-this-mean-the-Puranic-deities-we-worship-and-stories-we-read-are-false-from-a-Vedic-perspective) and got some great answers as well - check out those answers for some more angles to look at this topic from.

Comment: As far as concerned, Puranas convey vedas by linking them to historical events. I am not understanding what you mean by "Vedic (Rgvedic primarily) texts are quite different from the Puranic stories we know"

Comment: Traditional Hindus consider all scriptures as holy and authoritative. It's only some outsiders who try to create a rift Vedas vs other scriptures.

Comment: If all scriptures were authoritative, there would be many inconsistencies. The Vedas refer to Indra the supreme king of gods, one of the 12 Adityas (sun-gods). In the Puranas, viSNu or shiva are usually described as supreme.

In the Vedas, soma is a drink. In the Puranas, soma refers to the moon.

In the Vedas, Vishnu is the younger brother of Indra. In the Puranas, only the Vamana avatara is the younger brother of Indra, and Vishnu is the lord of the lords.

In the Vedas, Indra (being supreme) often commands Vishnu, but in the Puranas, Indra runs to Vishnu for help.

Comment: As I told such inconsistencies are accepted by traditional and practicing Hindus. Outsiders, who have no business with the religion, try to create the rift .. I think that's part of their job.

Comment: In the Vedas, Indra, the supreme commander, orders Vishnu to kill Vritra. In the Puranas, Indra seeks Vishnu's divine help to kill Vritra. 
In the Vedas, Rudra is a storm deity, with parents. In the Puranas, Shiva is described as Swayambhu (self born). These are the kind of inconsistencies I was referring to. We can't just "accept" both versions as true, right? So I was asking whether these Puranic accounts are false from the Vedic perspective.

Comment: @Rickross who are those out siders. Are they indologist or western hindu scholar.

Comment: @Apps247 Indra of Vedas is different from Indra of Puranas. Indra, Varuna, Vishnu etc. all are different names of Parabrahma in vedas. While puranic Indra is just a king of gods and and not worthy of worship.

Comment: @Apps247 read this https://www.quora.com/How-is-vedic-Indra-different-from-Indra-mentioned-in-Purans-and-epics-like-Ramayan-and-Mahabharat/answer/Kiron-Krishnan-1

Comment: @SanatanDarshan that article highlights the differences clearly. Now relating it to my question - does that mean from a Vedic perspective, common Hindu beliefs today don't hold weight?

Comment: @Apps247 no it is not.